# How to download the latest OS X El Capitan? Not update, not install, only download

Tags: itunes, macos

How can I download the latest El Capitan? If I follow http://www.apple.com/osx/ it offers me to upgrade.

When I open https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=1018109117&mt=12&ls=1&v0=www-us-osx-how-app-elcapitan there is a button "Download". I click it and the circle near it starts spinning indicating like download has started. The "Download" button itself got disabled. But nothing really happening. It has been spinning for 15 min now and I cannot see any OS downloads.

Where does it download OS to? How can I know exact state of the downloading? Now it looks like a bug - it spins but nothing is happening.

Comment: You can see a progress indicator on the Launchpad icon in the Dock. The download itself is 6GB & may take some time.

Comment: Do you intend to transfer the 6 GB download to a flash drive? In other words, do you intend to install on a different Mac?

Comment: In some cases you get an app called "Install OS X El Capitan.app" in the "Applications" folder.  If you then quit when it asks you to start installation, that app will still be there, and can be moved.

Comment: Related - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos